# Compare two files based on dates in the file names

Tags: powershell

Below are two file names:

```
$f1 = "abc_2019_01_30_5816789.bak","xyz_2019_01_26_4690992.bak"
$f2 = "abc_2019_01_31_3142809.bak","xyz_2019_01_27_8319704.bak"
```

I want to compare based on the dates in the file names.
If the file starts with same name like "abc" and then compare with the date in it.

I tried below:

```
if ($f1 -lt $f2) {Write-Host "true"}
```

Comment: How is this only two file names, or was that perhaps just a typing mistake? I'm not quite sure just what you are trying to compare and, well... why.

Comment: with your declaration $f1 and $f2 was arrays and doesn't understand what comparaison do you whant to perform ? /

Comment: corrected the requirements.

Comment: What do the numbers after the date mean (`5816789`)? Are they significant parts of the equation?

Comment: nope they are different for every file and they are the memory size of that file and i dont have to use it for the compare

Comment: `$f1` and `$f2` are two arrays. How would one array be "less than" another array? If you want to compare filenames based on date substrings in the filenames: extract those substrings from the filenames, convert them to dates, then compare the resulting `DateTime` objects.

Comment: The dates in the file names are already in sortable format, so you could simply do `($f1 + $f2) | Sort-Object` The file on top will be the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and modify according to your requirement:

```
$f1 = "abc_2019_01_30_5816789.bak"
$f2 = "abc_2019_01_31_3142809.bak"

$regex = '\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}'

[String]$f1date = [regex]::match($f1,'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}').Value
$f1date = $f1date.Replace('_','-')
[datetime]$f1date = $f1date

[String]$f2date = [regex]::match($f2,'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}').Value
$f2date = $f2date.Replace('_','-')
[datetime]$f2date = $f2date

if($f1date -lt $f2date) {Write-Host "true"}
```